# Passing variable from filter

Tags: filters

I have this filter:

```
function wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects( $items){
    global $count4footer;

    foreach( $items as $item ){

        $count = countPosts($item->ID);
        if($count!==false){
            $item->title = $item->title." ($count)";
            $count4footer[$item->ID]=$count;
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects' );
```

I need to pass variable to the footer, but is printing `null`, I added `global $count4footer;` to the function , but to no effect.
How can I access this value later?

Comment: You need `global $count4footer;` at the top of `footer.php` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `$count4footer` *outside* the function `wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects`.

```
$count4footer = array( );

function wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects( $items){
    global $count4footer;

    foreach( $items as $item ){

        $count = countPosts($item->ID);
        if($count!==false){
            $item->title = $item->title." ($count)";
            $count4footer[$item->ID]=$count;
        }
    }

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects' );
```